# Prevent <canvas> re-render on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, react-hooks

I am using hooks, with React 16.9.

I have a component that renders an HTML canvas element. The issue is that I have event handlers that change component state, which in turn re-renders my canvas element and erases the drawing I've done. If I were using class components, I may be able to add `shouldComponentUpdate() {return false;}`, but I am not sure of the equivalent for hooks.

```
const Canvas = () => {

const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
const myRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {

  // perform a one-time drawing on the canvas element that should be retained throughout state changes

  myRef.current.addEventListener('onmouseover', () => setHover(true));
  myRef.current.addEventListener('onmouseout', () => setHover(false));

}, [])

return (
  {hover && <p>Hovering</p>}
  <canvas ref = {myRef}>
);

}
```

Comment: useEffect(() => {// logic},[hover]), to imitate the shouldComponentUpdate you need to pass the second argument which is array deps you can pass the hover variable so whenever it changes only the useEffect will trigger, check it whether it worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an inaccurate understanding of the concept of state, in 99.99% of cases it is used to keep the component updated. If you do not need to update the component, you can use ref.

Also you can put the canvas into a separate component and add callbacks to events of hover. Don't forget to wrap child component of canvas in memo function, that prevent to re-render.

Comment: Actually, I am using the component state to update the UI. I updated the example to reflect that. useMemo is what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this react functional component needs to behave like a React.PureComponent try wrapping your entire react functional component in a react.memo(function).

```
const Canvas = React.memo(() => {

const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
const myRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {

  // perform a one-time drawing on the canvas element that should be retained throughout state changes

  myRef.current.addEventListener('onmouseover', () => setHover(true));
  myRef.current.addEventListener('onmouseout', () => setHover(false));

}, [])

return (
  {hover && <p>Hovering</p>}
  <canvas ref = {myRef}>
);

})
```